# Second submit button not working like first one

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Right now I am really confused and have been working on this problem for a couple hours now so I thought I would post on here and maybe get some feedback. So I have a program that runs this search tool on a file. The file either comes from user input generated into a file or a user actually uploading the file. I have 2 submit buttons where the first one goes with user generated files and the second one has to do with a user uploading a file.

The problem I have is that I have the same exact code for the second submit button (All that changes is the way the program gets the file) but for some reason by second submit button doesnt work. Nothing is generated and the execution of the search tool does not occur. I know this because there is not an output file created.

I was wondering if someone knows why my second button doesnt perform like the first button....

Here is my code...

```
  <form method="POST", action="/~cs4380sp15grp4/home/blast.php" class="form-inline">
  <textarea id="BlastSearch" type="textarea" name="BlastSearch" class="form-control">
            Database:
            <select id="database" name="database" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Archaea">Archaea</option>
            </select>
            Threshold:
            <select id="evalue" name="evalue" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0.0001">0.0001</option>
                            <option value="0.001">0.001</option>
            </select>
 Hits:
            <select id="hits" name="hits" class="form-control">
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                            <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>
            <button id="run" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Run BLAST</button>
            <button type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-info">Clear</button>
    </form>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST" class="form-inline"/>
         <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="form-control"/>
         <input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload" class="form-control"/>
         <input type="reset" value="reset" name="reset" class="form-control"/>
    </form>

   <form method="POST", action="/~cs4380sp15grp4/home/blast.php" class="form-inline">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit file" name="submit2" class="form-control"/>
            </form>

<?php
    //connects to db
    //Insert the values into the database
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            //declare variables to what the user defines them as
            $db = $_POST['database'];
            $evalue = $_POST['evalue'];
            $sequence = $_POST['BlastSearch'];
            $hits = $_POST['hits'];

            //create a new .fasta file and put the sequence the user wants to search for in that file
            $file = 'uploads/'.$mysqli->insert_id.'.fasta';
            $header = ">gi|129295|sp|P01013|OVAX_CHICK GENE X PROTEIN (OVALBUMIN-RELATED)\n";
            $current = $header . $_POST['BlastSearch'];
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
            $userid = $_SESSION['uid'];

            //insert the values into the database
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `Job` (`uid`, `input`, `status`, `start_time`, `finish_time`) VALUES ('1', '" . $sequence . "', 'running' , NOW(), NOW())");
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `BLAST`(`db_name`, `evalue`, `job_id`) VALUES ('" . $db . "','" . $evalue . "', '".$mysqli->insert_id."')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

            //execute the BLAST Tool
            // Do this execute statement if the user inputs his own sequence. (Use new.fasta)
            exec('/students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall -p blastp -d db -i /students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/public_html/home/uploads/'.$mysqli->insert_id.'.fasta -m'.$evalue.' -o outputSEQ -v'.$hits.' -b'.$hits);
            }


    if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){

     //declare variables to what the user defines them as
            $db = $_POST['database'];
            $evalue = $_POST['evalue'];
            $sequence = $_POST['BlastSearch'];
            $hits = $_POST['hits'];
            $userid = $_SESSION['uid'];

            //insert the values into the database
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `Job` (`uid`, `input`, `status`, `start_time`, `finish_time`) VALUES ('1', '" . $sequence . "', 'running' , NOW(), NOW())");

            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `BLAST`(`db_name`, `evalue`, `job_id`) VALUES ('" . $db . "','" . $evalue . "', '".$mysqli->insert_id."')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));


exec('/students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall -p blastp -d db -i /students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/public_html/home/uploads/sample.fasta -m '.$evalue.' -o outputFILE -v'.$hits.' -b'.$hits);

   }

    $mysqli->close();



?>
```

I dont understand it. basically the exec function works in the first submit button, but the exec function doesnt work in the second one... I can go into terminal and run the second exec function and it runs perfectly fine. Is it because of the action for the second submit being upload.php? I could see it being that....

EDIT1: I just tried creating a new form specifically for that button and making the action the same as the first submit buttons form. It didnt work though :( any help is appreciated!

Comment: I could not understand why do you use three forms?

Comment: you can not get other form field through another form submit button, so you will not get  $_POST['database']; in second submit button, that's why your query is throwing an error. you should enable display error to get that.

Comment: but you only have your inputs in the first form so you are only posting them when you post the first form. As sємsєм says, you need to merge all your forms (with the same action) into one and then you can do the checks on which submit button you have clicked.

Comment: These are apart from the mistakes in your code , like an extra comma etc.
Could you please explain what functionality you are trying to achieve with this three forms ? 

You are trying to get fileds like $_POST['database'] in the second condition, when the second form submit2 doesnt have those fields . It is adviseable to rethink about the use case and redo the forms, you may be able to get this done with one form alone.

Comment: I rollback the edit as the question had been totally re-written and therefore the answers did not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is few issues in your code you pasted.

1. In first form `textarea` does not have closing tag.
2. In third form you have a comma (,) after `method="Post"`
3. Your question is about second submit button and you have created 3 forms.

Answer (score 0):

Should that comma after the method=POST be there?  I can't actually see why it would make any difference, but it's not going to help.  Having multiple forms on a page is valid of course, but it's sometimes better to have just one form and use Javascript behind multiple 'normal' buttons to set the enctype, method, action set and required defaults and then submit the form programatically.

Answer (score -1):

Provide the following hidden inputs in the corresponding forms in order to get the $_POST['submit'] and $_POST['submit2'] in the server side php:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="submit" />

<input type="hidden" value="1" name="submit2" />
```

Try this:

```
<form method="POST", action="/~cs4380sp15grp4/home/blast.php" class="form-inline">
  <textarea id="BlastSearch" type="textarea" name="BlastSearch" class="form-control">
            Database:
            <select id="database" name="database" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Archaea">Archaea</option>
            </select>
            Threshold:
            <select id="evalue" name="evalue" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0.0001">0.0001</option>
                            <option value="0.001">0.001</option>
            </select>
 Hits:
            <select id="hits" name="hits" class="form-control">
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                            <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="submit" />
            <button id="run" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Run BLAST</button>
            <button type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-info">Clear</button>
    </form>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST" class="form-inline"/>
         <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="form-control"/>
         <input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload" class="form-control"/>
         <input type="reset" value="reset" name="reset" class="form-control"/>
    </form>

   <form method="POST", action="/~cs4380sp15grp4/home/blast.php" class="form-inline">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="submit2" />
                    <input type="submit" value="submit file"  class="form-control"/>
            </form>

<?php
    //connects to db
    //Insert the values into the database
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            //declare variables to what the user defines them as
            $db = $_POST['database'];
            $evalue = $_POST['evalue'];
            $sequence = $_POST['BlastSearch'];
            $hits = $_POST['hits'];

            //create a new .fasta file and put the sequence the user wants to search for in that file
            $file = 'uploads/'.$mysqli->insert_id.'.fasta';
            $header = ">gi|129295|sp|P01013|OVAX_CHICK GENE X PROTEIN (OVALBUMIN-RELATED)\n";
            $current = $header . $_POST['BlastSearch'];
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
            $userid = $_SESSION['uid'];

            //insert the values into the database
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `Job` (`uid`, `input`, `status`, `start_time`, `finish_time`) VALUES ('1', '" . $sequence . "', 'running' , NOW(), NOW())");
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `BLAST`(`db_name`, `evalue`, `job_id`) VALUES ('" . $db . "','" . $evalue . "', '".$mysqli->insert_id."')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

            //execute the BLAST Tool
            // Do this execute statement if the user inputs his own sequence. (Use new.fasta)
            exec('/students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall -p blastp -d db -i /students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/public_html/home/uploads/'.$mysqli->insert_id.'.fasta -m'.$evalue.' -o outputSEQ -v'.$hits.' -b'.$hits);
            }


    if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){

     //declare variables to what the user defines them as
            $db = $_POST['database'];
            $evalue = $_POST['evalue'];
            $sequence = $_POST['BlastSearch'];
            $hits = $_POST['hits'];
            $userid = $_SESSION['uid'];

            //insert the values into the database
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `Job` (`uid`, `input`, `status`, `start_time`, `finish_time`) VALUES ('1', '" . $sequence . "', 'running' , NOW(), NOW())");

            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `BLAST`(`db_name`, `evalue`, `job_id`) VALUES ('" . $db . "','" . $evalue . "', '".$mysqli->insert_id."')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));


exec('/students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall -p blastp -d db -i /students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/public_html/home/uploads/sample.fasta -m '.$evalue.' -o outputFILE -v'.$hits.' -b'.$hits);

   }

    $mysqli->close();



?>
```

Comment: In which form of the three forms?

Comment: In the respective forms where you need to identify which form is submitted.

Comment: There is submit button with same name already exist. Could you please explain why it needed to create hidden element with same name.

Comment: @sємsєм use the edited code. Here submit, submit2 hidden variables are using to identify which form is been submitted. So put them in the corresponding forms